# Run executable from python such that it crashes without GUI or asking for user input

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have a python program that runs a console executable in Windows using subprocess.Popen.

It works well, except that if the executable crashes, it shows a message box indicating the error and the user must click 'OK' for the python script to continue.

How can I run the executable from python such that it won't open a message box if it crashes?

Comment: You cannot avoid that an external script uses GUI based messages - afaik

Comment: Clarify what you mean "crashes" and where the message box comes from-- if python opens it, there's probably something you can do. If the Windows console opens it, there might be still.

Answer (score 0):

Using my facilities for psychic debugging, I believe [this is the problem you're having](http://www.smarttechtips.com/tips/disable-windows-crash-report-windows-7/).

In short: you'll need to disable crash notification in Windows to resolve the dialog box that's appearing when your subprocess crashes. Though if this is required, it's more desirable to figure out *why* your subprocess is crashing in the first place.